# I keep getting a TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

This is part of a program that will tell the user what key stage they are in.

```
YearG = input("What year group are you in?");
if (YearG == ("Year 1") ("Year 2")):
```

I expect the result to be `You are in key stage X!`

Instead, I get

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

How can I fix that? *EDIT*:See answer below for how I fixed this issue, No further action needed.

Comment: I would suspect `(YearG == ("Year 1") ("Year 2"))` is not valid syntax for these values. Maybe you need an `in` operator instead of an == test? You could always do a `for item in items` loop and test iteratively...

Comment: `if YearG == "Year 1" or YearG == "Year2":`

I think that is what you are trying to do

Comment: You probably want `if YearG in ("Year 1", "Year 2"):`.  The part it's complaining about is `("Year 1") ("Year 2")`, which boils down to `"Year 1"("Year 2")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is not a parenthesis language, I believe you want the below.

```
>>> YearG = input('What year group are you in?')
What year group are you in?10
>>> YearG
'10'
>>> if YearG == '10':
...     print('You entered 10')
... else:
...     print('You entered something other than 10')
... 
You entered 10
```